# Errors while using paperclip in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

At the moment I try to replace attachment_fu fileuploading plugin with paperclip.

But there are some errors while uploading:

My controller looks like this:

```
def create
add_breadcrumb 'breadcrumb.upload_file', {:action => :new}

puts "BLUBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
puts params[:upload]

    @upload = Upload.create(params[:upload])
    @upload.lecturer_id = current_user.id
    if @upload.save
        flash[:notice] = I18n.t("flash.saved")
        redirect_to :action => :index
    else
        render :action => :new
    end
end
```

and my model like this:

```
puts has_attached_file :image, :default_url => :file_system
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => [:image, 'audio/mpeg', 'application/mp3', 'application/octet-stream']
```

While uploading I got this error:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in UploadsController#create

unknown attribute: uploaded_data

app/controllers/uploads_controller.rb:24:in `create'
```

Update:

```
{"name"=>"TEST", "uploaded_data"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000005518a38 @original_filename="2014-09-26 18.14.22.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload[uploaded_data]\"; filename=\"2014-09-26 18.14.22.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150415-12671-190wpi5>>}
```

Update: thats not that what I wanted. The migration generetad some new columns in database, how can I return to the previus version? is there a demigrate coammand?

[image]

Comment: Looks to me as if you named your `<input type="file">` form element wrong (`uploaded_data` instead of `image`). Please add the form partial and a log entry showing the POSTed parameters from the form submit.

Comment: Is *BLUBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB* relevant to your question? ;-)

Comment: yes thats absolutely essential ;)

Comment: can you show the output of params[:upload]

Comment: @Sagar.Patil thanks, when you see my initial question added code there is also a puts for the purams. --- I've added the output of `puts param[:upload]` above

Comment: have you seen my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To revert the migration from Paperclip you can use either:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=_current_migration_number
```

or

```
rake db:rollback
```

Until your previous state. Then you can create a new migration like this:

```
class ChangeUploadToPaperclip < ActiveRecord::Migration
  change do
    rename_column :uploads, :content_type, :upload_content_type 
    rename_column :uploads, :filename, :upload_filename
    rename_column :uploads, :size, :upload_file_size
    add_column :uploads, :upload_updated_at, :datetime
    # Warning: the following will remove your old data, irreversible.
    remove_column :uploads, :width 
    remove_column :uploads, :height 
    remove_column :uploads, :thumbnail 
  end
end
```

But there could be potential errors between your old storage and Paperclips way of storing files.

In this answer I assumed that your model `has_attached_file :upload`.

If you have another name for the attached file, update every `upload` and `uploads` accordingly.

**Edit**
The migration file needs to have a certain name:

```
20150417125122_change_upload_to_paperclip.rb
```

(the date-string is auto generated, I copied this from comment below.)

This is because Rails will look for `ChangeUploadToPaperclip` only if there is underscore between.

If you have `changeuploadtopaperclip.rb` it would look for `Changeuploadtopaperclip`.

**Running special migration**

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20150417125122
```

Comment: can I add this in the migrattion file?

Comment: thanks, I have done what you have said ... but without any effect. I called `sudo rake db:migrate` after changing the migration file. but nothing changed in database...

Comment: Did you rollback before?
Was the new migration run?
Why do you use sudo? Are you doing this directly on the server?
In that case - ALWAYS make this things as the server-user running the railsapp, for example www-data.

Comment: yes i've done the rollback before. Hope so. My server is at the moment a virtual debian server on my computer.

Comment: I tried it with `sudo rake db:migrate 20150417125122_changeuploadtopaperclip.rb` again and got this error:

`Don't know how to build task '20150417125122_changeuploadtopaperclip.rb'`

Comment: thanks, but nothing changed. `Don't know how to build task '20150417125122_change_upload_to_paperclip.rb' `

Comment: okay now it runs without error, bot nothing changed on database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75694/discussion-between-davidwessman-and-felix).

Comment: Hi Sorry, was the whole day on road. Thanks for your help. I've checked it up and renamed the file like in your post. I got this error: `
ActiveRecord::UnknownMigrationVersionError: No migration with version number 20150417125122`

Comment: Hi now I got this error: `Upload model missing required attr_accessor for 'upload_file_name'`

Comment: Go into the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75694/discussion-between-davidwessman-and-felix

Answer (score 1):

your column for image is `image` from your model structure. But the data in params the image is coming in `params[:model_name][uploaded_data]`. 
Your model doesnt contain any column with name `uploaded_data` that too for a attached_file

In your `form_for` you should have this

```
= f.file_field :image
```

not

```
= f.file_field :uploaded_data
```

In this way your params would look like

```
{"name"=>"TEST", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000005518a38 @original_filename="2014-09-26 18.14.22.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload[uploaded_data]\"; filename=\"2014-09-26 18.14.22.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150415-12671-190wpi5>>}
```

And it wont give you any error

GO through the gem on github [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

You nee to create migration file like this:

```
class AddAvatarColumnsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_attachment :model_name, :[image]
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :model_name, :[image]
  end
end
```

Or use the generator:

```
rails generate paperclip model_name [image]
```

Comment: hi, thanks, for this solution, but now i got this error `Upload model missing required attr_accessor for 'image_file_name'`

Comment: have u used the paperclip generator to generate required migration and migrated them. Because it looks like u dont have required columns in or model/table

Comment: Hi Thanks. I run `rails generate paperclip upload [image]` .. so then there was a migrate file created `db/migrate/20150417125122_add_attachment_[image]_to_uploads.rb` but when I run this i got this error: `ActiveRecord::IllegalMigrationNameError: Illegal name for migration file: /var/www/xyz/xyz/db/migrate/20150417125122_add_attachment_[image]_to_uploads.rb
        (only lower case letters, numbers, and '_' allowed)`

Comment: Thanks, worked now, but I have a second question as well :) ... can you help me with this as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736467/ruby-on-rails-paperclip-questions

Comment: I've done the migration ... but now I have new colums in my upload table in db .. thats not that what I wanted. I've added a screenshot in itial question