# Ruby on Rails paperclip questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I want to use paperclip to upload files to server.
Errors are all cleaned now, but I don't know how to set the upload path.

My code looks like this:

upload class:

```
  puts has_attached_file :image, :default_url => :file_system
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => [:image,    'audio/mpeg', 'application/mp3', 'application/octet-stream']
```

I want to save uploads in project/public/uploads.

How can I realise this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then it should look like this:

```
has_attached_file :image,                     
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/uploads/:filename",
                    :url => "/uploads/:filename"
```

Comment: thanks for this, that works fine :) 

I've got a second question to the paperclip plugin, can you check it out pls? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647970/errors-while-using-paperclip-in-rails-app ... the last update of initial question is my problem at the moment

Comment: I do not have rep to comment there.  But you should use the Paperclip-generated db-columns. If you already have data in your old columns you can try to do a custom migration where you rename similar columns, might still cause some problems.

Comment: Not without modifying the Paperclip gem.
To revert a migration you can do `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=_input_the_migration_number`

You can also do `rake db:rollback`.

Comment: is there another file-upload plugin that I can use instead of this which can use my old colums?